# Passing an Object of arrays as a prop in React, then using loops to generate a table with the data

Tags: reactjs

**The object:**

```
let skillObj1 = {
      levels: [1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25, 29, 30, 32, 34, 35, 38],
      skills: [['axe', 'dagger', 'flail', 'polearm', 'spear', 'sword', 'archery', 'whip', 'evaluation', 'enhanced damage', 'staff', 'parry', 'rescue', 'recall'], ['dirt kicking'], ['hand to hand', 'second attack'],
      ['fast healing'], ['kick'], ['trip'], ['shield block'], ['dual wield', 'bash'], ['dodge'], ['haggle', 'lunge'], ['lash', 'disarm'], ['crush', 'warcry', 'meditation'],
      ['shield cleave', 'berserk'], ['third attack'], ['recovery'], ['dual parry', 'pugil'], ['counter'], ['ground control', 'defend'],
      ['fourth attack'], ['battle tactics'], ['enhanced damage II'], ['enlist'], ['block retreat']]
    };
```

**The loop I'd like to be using, but obviously is incorrect:**

```
tableData(props) {
    let data = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.levels.length; i++) {
      data.concat('<tr><td>Level ' + props.levels[i] + '</td>');
      for (var j = 0; j < props.skills[i].length; j++) {

        if (j % 2 === 0) {
          data.concat('<td>' + props.skills[i][j] + '</td</tr>');
          if (j !== props.skills[i].length - 1) { data.concat('<tr><td></td>');}
        } else {
          data.concat('<td>' + props.skills[i][j] + '</td>');
          if (j === props.skills[i].length - 1) {data.concat('<td></td></tr>');}
        }

      }
    }
    return data;
  };
```

**My Render:**

```
render() {
  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><strong>Your list of skills:</strong></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {this.tableData}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
  }
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I want to make a table with 3 columns, so 3 `<td>` per row. In the first `<td>` will be the level that the ability is gained. That will only be shown in the first row where the abilities for that level begin. All consecutive rows will have the first `<td>` blank until reaching the next level's entries. The actual abilities will be in only the 2nd and 3rd columns/ `<td>`s.

**Kinda like this, sorry if it's a bad example:**

```
|-----|-----|-----|
|Lvl1 | axe |sword|
|-----|flail|-----|
|Lvl2 |kick |trip |
|-----|punch|smell|
|-----|slap |-----|
|Lvl5 |-----|-----|
```

**Edit:**

I am seeing a lot of people using the `.map()` and `.filter()` methods to handle similar things, but my problem is that I have several conditions that I'm not sure how to handle.

If I try to just print an array of `<td>` it works fine with `.map()` but either my JavaScript/jsx skill is just really bad right now, or there's a better way to deal with the conditions so it prints in the format I'm looking for.

**Edit2**

Now I'm attempting to get something like this to work in the render:

```
let levels = this.props.skills.levels;
let skills = this.props.skills.skills;
{levels.map(function(obj, i) {
    return (
        <tr><td>Level {obj}</td>
        skills[i].map(function(obj2, j) {
            if (j % 2 === 0) {
                <TableData skill={obj2[i][j]} /></tr>
                if (j !== obj2[i].length - 1) { <tr><TableData /> }
            } else {
                <TableData skill={obj2[i][j]} /></td>;
                if (j === props.skills[i].length - 1) {<TableData /></tr>}
            }
        });
    )
)}
```

**Edit 3**

I thought perhaps a ternary operator might be appropriate. I'm still getting a lot of jsx errors because the jsx elements are not closed "properly" even though the purpose of the operator is to close them.

```
{levels.map(function(obj, i) {
    return (<tr><td>Level {obj}</td>
            skills[i].map(function(obj2, j) {
              (j % 2 === 0) ?
                (j !== obj2[i][j].length - 1) ? (<TableData skill={obj2[i][j]} /></tr><tr><TableData />) : (<TableData skill={obj2[i][j]} /></tr>)
                : (j === obj2[i].length - 1) ? (<TableData skill={obj2[i][j]} /></td><TableData /></tr>) : (<TableData skill={obj2[i][j]} /></td>);
            });
          )
  )}
```

**Edit 4 Getting Closer**

```
  tableData(props) {
    let levels = this.props.skills.levels;
    let skills = this.props.skills.skills;
    let data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
      //<tr>beginning
      data.push(<Level level={i} key={i * 100} />);
      for (var j = 0; j <= skills[i].length; j++) {

        if (j % 2 === 0) {
          data.push(<TableData skill={skills[i][j]} key={i + j} />); //</tr> end
          if (j !== skills[i].length - 1) { data.push(<TableData key={(i + j) * 200} />);}//<tr> beginning
        } else {
          data.push(<TableData skill={skills[i][j]} key={i + j} />);
          if (j === skills[i].length - 1) {data.push(<TableData key={(i + j) * 100} />)} //</tr> end
        }

      }
    }
    return data;
  };
```

With this function, I am able to print everything in table data tags. However, I still can't place the table row tags where they need to go. If I don't close the tags I get a jsx error even if the end result theoretically should be correct.

Comment: Is each array in skills supposed to go with the level?

Comment: @Yatrix Yes, the index of each level corresponds to the index of the array inside the skills array. So level 1 at index 0 corresponds to ['axe', 'dagger', 'flail',...] which is also index 0 of skills.

Comment: So in the first <td> is the lvl, in the second td there are the skills but what should be in the third td ?

Comment: @Stevetro In the third td there will either be another skill or an empty td

Comment: Something like that https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-cdn-vgqfx ?

Comment: @Stevetro I'm going to have to stare at that a while, but I think it looks like an awesome solution. I haven't used React.Fragment before, so I'll also have to look into that. Can you post that as an answer so I can give you credit for the solution later?

Comment: @Stevetro I've also never iterated over more than 1 before, so that's also an eye-opener. I mean, I "knew" I could do it, but having never seen it in practice, it just didn't occur to me to do it like that. Thank you, sir. This solution is amazing.

Comment: Happy if I could help :). I posted my answer, so you'll can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way is to structure the data first and render it later, so you dont have to mess around with closing tags etc. You could use a for loop and iterate over every 2 item to create the table.

```
<div className="App">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {levels.map((item, i) => {
            var skl = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < skills[i].length; j = j + 2) {
              if (j < 2) {
                skl.push(
                  <tr>
                    <td>Level {item}</td>
                    <td>{skills[i][0]}</td>
                    <td>{skills[i][1]}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              } else {
                skl.push(
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{skills[i][j]}</td>
                    <td>{skills[i][j + 1]}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              }
            }
            return (
              <React.Fragment>
                {skl.map((item) => {
                  return item;
                })}
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-cdn-vgqfx